# Google search bot doesn't see bound content in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, search-engine

I wrote a website using AngularJS and I'm having trouble getting google search bot to see it correctly. Google's search console shows that the bot only sees the double curlies (" {{ someData }}") and not the data that is bound to variables. Also, the view is not there. The ng-view tag is empty. So basically, its just the index.html file with no view and no data. I'm using websocket to fetch the data from my server and clearly the bot is not waiting for the data to be inserted into the DOM, nor the view. I have set $locationProvider to html5mode.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

I have been searching for answers but have been unsuccessful. It is my understanding that google's search bot should be able to handle javascript. I have seen in posts on stackoverflow and elsewhere that since 2014 or so, it would no longer be necessary to serve google bot html from the server with, for example PhantomJS. Is this true?

Is there a way to control when google's search bot considers the page ready? Or should I just serve google html?

In case you have questions as to the code, it can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jarnovirta/angularBlog).